# Joomla Website showing while color while opening website (only Home Page is white and remaining pages working fine)

Tags: web, joomla, hosting, cpanel, joomla3.0

When we are opening the website domain ([www.mylink.com](http://www.mylink.com)). It was showing in White Color, Bit if i am opening any sub pages ([www.mylink.com/product](http://www.mylink.com/product)). We also Tried Updating to the Joomla version

1. With Website link(white screen)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYbSU.png)
2. With Website link(with  adding/index.php)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3JNG.png)

Can Anyboday can help in this

We Tried updating joomla version
Re installing of plugin
Checking Domain

Answer (score 0):

there could be 3 possible issues:

1. Corrupted Joomla core files
   Major Joomla files include administrator, components, cache, etc. During file uploads and in the cause of website management, files can become corrupted and the corruption of these core files can lead to Joomla blank pages. Usually, this can be avoided either by upgrading the Joomla version or by restoring a healthy backup or reinstalling the core files
2. Changes in the server directory structure
   During migration, it is essential to transfer the website files and databases from the source to the destination server. Different servers will usually have different directory structures. For instance in Plesk servers, the website root folder will be at /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs. Similarly, in cPanel it is at /home/username/public_html.

So it is always important to make sure that files and folders have the correct directory tree. This will prevent the blank page occurrence.

3. Incorrect rules in .htaccess file
   Many Joomla website admins use rewrite rules to tweak the look and feel of the site. Often incorrect rules in the .htaccess file can also cause Joomla to blank page. In cases where .htaccess creates problems, you can copy and paste default htaccess code to correct the rules. joomla default htaccess:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  (C) 2005 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems with some server configurations.
# It is required for the use of Apache mod_rewrite, but it may have already been set by
# your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in this .htaccess file.
# If using it causes your site to produce an error, comment it out (add # to the
# beginning of the line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef urls. If
# they work, then it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need to
# set it here.
##

## MISSING CSS OR JAVASCRIPT ERRORS
#
# If your site looks strange after enabling this file, then your server is probably already
# gzipping css and js files and you should comment out the GZIP section of this file.
##

## OPENLITESPEED
#
# If you are using an OpenLiteSpeed web server then any changes made to this file will
# not take effect until you have restarted the web server.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## No directory listings
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Suppress mime type detection in browsers for unknown types
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

## Protect against certain cross-origin requests. More information can be found here:
## https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cross-Origin_Resource_Policy_(CORP)
## https://web.dev/why-coop-coep/
#<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#   Header always set Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy "same-origin"
#   Header always set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp"
#</IfModule>

## Disable inline JavaScript when directly opening SVG files or embedding them with the object-tag
<FilesMatch "\.svg$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'none'"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

## These directives are only enabled if the Apache mod_rewrite module is enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
    # If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
    # below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
    # This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
    #
    # Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
    # Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    # Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    # Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
    #
    ## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

    ## Begin - Custom redirects
    #
    # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
    # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
    # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
    #
    ## End - Custom redirects

    ##
    # Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
    # is not directly related to physical file paths.
    # Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
    ##

    # RewriteBase /

    ## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
    #
    # PHP FastCGI fix for HTTP Authorization, required for the API application
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    # -- SEF URLs for the API application
    # If the requested path starts with /api, the file is not /api/index.php
    # and the request has not already been internally rewritten to the
    # api/index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/index\.php
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the /api/index.php script
    RewriteRule .* api/index.php [L]
    # -- SEF URLs for the public frontend application
    # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
    # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    #
    ## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
</IfModule>

## These directives are only enabled if the Apache mod_rewrite module is disabled
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When Apache mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect
        # of the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

## GZIP
## These directives are only enabled if the Apache mod_headers module is enabled.
## This section will check if a .gz file exists and if so will stream it
##     directly or fallback to gzip any asset on the fly
## If your site starts to look strange after enabling this file, and you see
##     ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in your browser console network tab,
##     then your server is already gzipping css and js files and you don't need this
##     block enabled in your .htaccess
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.css" "$1\.css\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist
    # and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept-encoding}" "gzip"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz" -s
    RewriteRule "^(.*)\.js" "$1\.js\.gz" [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule "\.css\.gz$" "-" [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule "\.js\.gz$" "-" [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
        # Serve correct encoding type.
        Header set Content-Encoding gzip

        # Force proxies to cache gzipped &
        # non-gzipped css/js files separately.
        Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```